# Is there any example of a Markov chain (discrete) with limit distribution (discrete) of heavy tail?

Tags: probability

Is there any example of a Markov chain with limit distribution (discrete) of heavy tail? In other words, a Markov chain whose limit distribution has infinite second moment?Already, thanks for the help!

Comment: So, you are considering Markov chains number valued, perhaps integer valued? Which chains on the integers have a stationary distribution that you can readily compute? One of the standard examples works...

Comment: Perhaps a random walk on 0 to positive infinity, with a reflecting barrier at 0; at each step, the probability of moving one integer left is 2/3 (one integer right 1/3).